# How do you send an image to Facebook Messenger on Android using Intent.ACTION_SEND?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, bitmap, facebook-messenger

The following code

```
final Intent sendImage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendImage.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
sendImage.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, theUri);
sendImage.setType("image/png");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendImage, "Send Image using "));
```

allows an image to be sent using any app (ex. Dropbox, Gmail, normal Messaging/Texting, Kik), but not the Facebook Messenger app.

Every time I choose the Facebook Messenger app as the app to use to send the photo, I get a "Sorry, Messenger can't handle this file type right now" exception.

The Uri is gotten from this method

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File imageFile = new File(path, "Yogamoji!" + ".png");
FileOutputStream fileOutPutStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(theAssets.open("emojis/" + fileName)).
compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutPutStream);

fileOutPutStream.flush();
fileOutPutStream.close();

return Uri.parse("file://" + imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: That's odd. If they couldn't handle it, they shouldn't be registered for it via the `<intent-filter>`. What is `theUri` exactly?

Comment: File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                File imageFile = new File(path, "Image" + ".png");
                FileOutputStream fileOutPutStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(theAssets.open( fileName)).
                        compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutPutStream);

                fileOutPutStream.flush();
                fileOutPutStream.close();

                return Uri.parse("file://" + imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: Between `flush()` and `close()`, add `getFD().sync()` and see if that helps. Also, use `Uri.fromFile()` rather than `Uri.parse()`.

Comment: I tried that code Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(imageFile.getAbsolutePath()));

and 
                fileOutPutStream.flush();
                fileOutPutStream.getFD().sync();
                fileOutPutStream.close();

But I still get that same error message

Comment: "I tried that code Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(imageFile.getAbsolutePath()));" -- use `Uri.fromFile(imageFile)`. That may not help, but it is a lot more efficient than what you are doing now.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar code that works. The only difference is:

```
sendImage.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(uriFile));
```

With

```
File uriFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+folderName+imageName);
```